# xsd2code generated throws error from XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, xsd2code

I have this part of and .xsd:

```
  <xs:element name="TimePeriod" nillable="false">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="StartTime" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element name="StopTime" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="false"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

With this code that I got from xsd2code:

```
public partial class ActivityTYPETimePeriod
{
    private System.DateTime itemField;
    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    public System.DateTime Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

public enum ItemChoiceType
{
    /// <remarks/>
    StartTime,
    /// <remarks/>
    StopTime,
}
```

This gives me this output:

```
<TimePeriod>
    <Item>2016-11-07T09:50:41.27</Item>
</TimePeriod>
```

but I would like to be like this if StartTime is the enum selection:

```
<TimePeriod>
    <StartTime>2016-11-07T09:50:41.27</StartTime>
</TimePeriod>
```

But when I use this decoration (also from xsd2code):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
public System.DateTime Item
```

I get thrown an exception saying:

> {"Missing 'TimeElementName' member needed for serialization of choice 'Item'."}

I can't put my finger on why it throws this error as I seem to remember it was working before I edited some other parts of my class and when I debug the code the `TimePeriod` recieves the correct values as well and the exception is not thrown until I hit the this line:
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

Is there another way to get my desired output or solve this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the lacking part that xsd2code did not generate for some reason was these two lines of code that also was required for it to work:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EndTime", typeof(System.DateTime))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("StartTime", typeof(System.DateTime))]
```

So the resulting decoration on `Item` is like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Sluttidpunkt", typeof(System.DateTime))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Starttidpunkt", typeof(System.DateTime))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
public System.DateTime Item
```